# How to convert a relative path to an absolute path in InstallShield?

Tags: installshield, installscript, installshield-2010

I have an IS project where I want to put some files under `TARGETDIR ^ ".." ^ "NewDir"`, and create the directory if it doesn't exist. The problem is that `CreateDir` requires an absolute path.

I'm thinking of trimming the trailing "\" from `TARGETDIR` then using `ParsePath(svReturnString, szPath, PATH)` to drop the last directory off `TARGETDIR`, but that is very specific to my particular example. Is there a more general purpose way of converting from relative to absolute paths?

Our installs default to `CompanyName\ProductName` so usually that will be `TARGETDIR`, but since products share resources we want to put common files in `CompanyName\Data`, `CompanyName\Log`, etc.